Programmatically change components of pytorch Model?
I am training a model in pytorch and would like to be able to programmatically change some components of the model architecture to check which works best without any if-blocks in the forward(). Consider a toy example:
import torch

class Model(torch.nn.Model):
   def __init__(self, layers: str, d_in: int, d_out: int):
      super().__init__()
      self.layers = layers
      linears = torch.nn.ModuleList([
         torch.nn.Linear(d_in, d_out),
         torch.nn.Linear(d_in, d_out),
      ])

   def forward(x1: torch.Tensor, x2: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
      if self.layers == "parallel":
         x1 = self.linears[0](x1)
         x2 = self.linears[1](x2)
         x = x1 + x2
      elif self.layers == "sequential":
         x = x1 + x2
         x = self.linears[0](x)
         x = self.linears[1](x)
      return x

My first intution was to provide external functions, e.g.
def parallel(x1, x2):
   x1 = self.linears[0](x1)
   x2 = self.linears[1](x2)
   return x1 + x2

and provide them to the model, like
class Model(torch.nn.Model):
   def __init__(self, layers: str, d_in: int, d_out: int, fn: Callable):
      super().__init__()
      self.layers = layers
      linears = torch.nn.ModuleList([
         torch.nn.Linear(d_in, d_out),
         torch.nn.Linear(d_in, d_out),
      ])
      self.fn = fn

   def forward(x1: torch.Tensor, x2: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
      x = self.fn(x1, x2)

but of course the function's scope does not know self.linears and I would also like to avoid having to pass each and every architectural element to the function.
Do I wish for too much? Do I have to "bite the sour apple" as it says in German and either have larger function signatures, or use if-conditions, or something else? Or is there a solution to my problem?

You could just use the if statement in the init function or in another function, for example:
from enum import Enum

class ModelType(Enum):
    Parallel = 1
    Sequential = 2
    
class Model(torch.nn.Model):
    def __init__(self, layers: str, d_in: int, d_out: int, model_type: ModelType):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = layers
        linears = torch.nn.ModuleList([
         torch.nn.Linear(d_in, d_out),
         torch.nn.Linear(d_in, d_out),
        ])
        self.model_type = model_type
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        if self.model_type == ModelType.Parallel:
            self.fn = self.parallel
        else if self.model_type == ModelType.Sequential::
            self.fn = self.sequential

    def forward(self, x1: torch.Tensor, x2: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        x = self.fn(x1, x2)
        return x
    
    def parallel(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.linears[0](x1)
        x2 = self.linears[0](x2)
        x = x1 + x2
        return x
    
    def sequential(self, x1, x2):
        x = x1 + x2
        x = self.linears[0](x)
        x = self.linears[0](x)
        return x

I hope it helps.
